Kubuntu multi-monitor clipping issue
My nvidia drivers got messed up with an update.  So I removed them all sudo apt-get remove --purge '^nvidia-.*' and tried installing them again using the cuda install instructions from nvidia.  I know cuda is something else, but I wanted cuda and it said it would install the drivers with it which it did.
distro=ubuntu2204
arch=x86_64
wget https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/$distro/$arch/cuda-keyring_1.1-1_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i cuda-keyring_1.1-1_all.deb
sudo apt-get install cuda-toolkit

The situation I am in is that I have two monitors which are slightly different resolutions.  There is black clipping which seems to be the size of one monitor but is centered on the other monitor.  The desktop and windows can not show through this black clipping, but the mouse does.
The right monitor is larger then the left monitor, and so when the clipping the size of the larger monitor is centered on the left monitor it only leaves a small slice of the right monitor not black.  .
The driver selection window in Kubuntu (software-properties-qt) said that I had a manually installed driver, from getting the one automatically installed with cuda.
I went ahead and had Kubuntu install the recommended drivers using the command
sudo ubuntu-drivers install

And now I am running the driver nvidia-driver-550 but the screen performance is still the same.  Another weird thing is that chrome no longer launches.  So I don't know if there is an acceleration thing that isn't enabled that it needs.  I am currently running Firefox to post this message.
I have tried teasing the resolutions or the relative location of the monitors with the KDE Display configuration.  But the black region which is clipping won't go away.
I am running Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS \n \l
I never finished adding the cuda tools to the PATH, but I am assuming that isn't the problem I am having right now.
Additional information, if I run google-chrome from the command line I get the error message:
$ google-chrome
[6600:6600:0405/161108.767006:FATAL:credentials.cc(127)] Check failed: . : Permission denied (13)
Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)

Additional info, I found this link gives the error message that google-chrome is giving me and I can start chrome if I provide the --no-sandbox argument.

I think I have my answer, I want to get CUDA and my second monitor going again before I am sure, but I finally figured out that somehow I was running an nvidia low latency kernel.  Once I enabled the grub menu, switched to the normal kernel, all the symptoms went away.  So watch out.  Somehow just doing updates got my kernel replaced.
